# How to structure dataflow between ReactJS UI components

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I feel the spaghetti sneaking in on me, in my code, and I find it hard to find best practices and general flow in ReactJS apps, beside the "pass data downwards to childs".

So, if you have two classes, I would pass information downwards like this:

```
var TodoList = React.Class({
     render: function(){
           return(
                <div>{this.props.data}</div>
           );
     }
});

var TodoCreate = ReactClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <TodoList data={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
});
```

if I want to trigger somthing in the parent I would pass in the function as a prop to the child:

```
<TodoList handleSomething={this.handleSomethingFunction} />
```

Easy enough, but how do you handle data communication between two different UI elements? In my specific case, I have a UI component, with it's own set of react classes, these talk fine internally, but when a specific task ends, I need to trigger an update in another UI component, an example of the relationship:

```
var ActionPanel = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
        return(
             <ActionPanelChild />
             ...
        );
   }
});

var ActionPanelChild = React.createClass({
   someTask: function(){
        var runs = 0;
        var intId = setInterval(function(){ 
           console.log("Running some specific task");
           runs++;
           if(runs == 10){
                clearInterval(intId);
                /*
                 * So here I should trigger the SomeUIPanel.state.number++ event, which cause SomeUIPanel to re-render and update.
                 */
           }
        }, 1000);
   },
   render: function(){
        return(
             <div>Some html</div>
        );
   }
});
```

Then the other panel which should receive an update in its state when the task "someTask" ends:

```
var SomeUIPanel = ReactClass(){
     getInitialState: function(){
          return { number: 0 };
     },
     render: function(){
          return(
               <div>{this.state.number}</div>
          );
     }
}
```

Should I gather the two objects in a wrapping React class/component?

And as a followup, when I have a wrapping class, should the outer-most component contain the entire state-data for all child components? The context I have is that I receive some data via AJAX, and that needs to rest at some place. Currently i then split that data up in new objects and pass the relevant parts down to the childs (in some cases with an instance of a property in more than one child).

Comment: Check out redux http://rackt.github.io/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at Flux , using stores and actions to solve your communication problems ?

I have used event streams , look at Bacon.js . These are nice since the stream only publishes events when something is listening to it.  see https://medium.com/@milankinen/good-bye-flux-welcome-bacon-rx-23c71abfb1a7

In terms of passing data down consider using context (e.g. https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html)

Hope that helps